# How to include .so file when build .egg with setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools

How can I build an .egg file include a '.so' file?

here is my file tree:

`` --setup.py
--__init__.py
--mcpack.py`
--mcpack.so ``

how can I make a package with mcpack.so in it?

I've tried using `pack_data`, it turns out .so file is packaged but not findable in python file.

Answer (score 2):

Put it in `native_libs.txt` and build the egg with `bdist_egg`, see [this section of the documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formats.html#native-libs-txt). You should, however, switch to [wheels](http://pythonwheels.com/) instead of eggs.

Shared object files are only distributable if you can guarantee the exact same tool chain that was used to build your `.so` is also present in every other distribution that is going to run it - this is highly unlikely and would break the distributable nature of egg files, that is unless you really only want to target a specific version of a Linux distribution.

Your egg, if installed in any other distribution than the one the .so was built on will not be able to be used.

If you want to build a distributable package containing native code have a look at [wheel files](http://pythonwheels.com/) and for wheels that can be distributed to all Linux OSs, have a look at [manylinux](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux).

Comment: I tried to add `_mcpack.so` into `native_libs.txt` and repacked, but still `ImportError: No module named _mcpack`.

Comment: What do you mean by saying " exact same tool chain "？

Comment: Built with same major GCC version, compatible versions of all linked libraries et al. Eg an .so built with GCC 5 will not run on GCC 4. Ditto for one linked against a shared library that is not compatible with the version of the library on the new system. The name is `mcpack`, no? If you extract the .egg, the .so should be present after `bdist_egg`. If not, it will not be able to be imported.

Comment: I'm assuming the `.so` in question is being built by `setup.py` via its `Extensions` capability, btw. If it was downloaded from elsewhere there's no guarantee it will import on your system, same reasons as above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems that this is not runable because of this issue [link](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formats.html#zip-file-issues). The `.so` is downloaded and I don't have the src files. I'll try `pkg_resources` to solve this.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I'd recommend moving to wheels instead, it is much easier to use and directly caters to this exact use case. Link in answer above.

Comment: It turns out I asked a wrong question. I was trying to use the module in the `.so` file on spark engine, I thought I should pack it into egg. However, the only thing I needed to do is to put it after `--files` when submit spark task, like `--files _mcpack.so`.